# openpyxl dataframe_to_rows stops rows processing on NaN?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

Very simply my code looks something like this

```py
wb = Workbook()
sheet = wb.active

df = load_data_from_sql(SQL_QUERY)

for row in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=True):
    sheet.append(row)
```

the resultant df from my SQL query looks something like this

```
name, birthday, favorite_color
'john', '1993-08-02', 'red'
'chris', NaN, 'blue'
'steven', '1993-04-11', 'orange'
```

What ends up happening when writing to the workbook is that `john` gets written, then `chris`gets written up until the birthday column - then the processing on the rest of the rows stops completely and steven never gets written.

Temporarily, the way I've been dealing with it is just doing something like `df.fillna('NaN')`. Is this the correct way to handle this? Or should openpyxl actually properly handle NaN values when calling dataframe to rows?

Comment: How do you write back to Excel? Doing `df.to_excel()` works fine for me when `NaN` is in dataframe.

Comment: well I'm using the openpyxl workbook, so I use `wb.save()`. `sheet.append()` will append to a sheet in a specific workbook and then saving the entire workbook would save the sheets as well. I can confirm that aspect of it is working properly.